# Create file in dropbox using api

Tags: apex, rest-api, callout, httprequest

I want to create file in dropbox using api. I have gone through [api documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#files_put).

I have tried this:

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
String endpoint = 'https://content.dropboxapi.com/1/files_put/auto/home/Private%20Salesforce%20Documents/Opportunities/test1.txt'; 

req.setEndpoint(endpoint); 
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + 'testAccessCode');
req.setMethod('PUT');
//req.setBody('testBody');
req.setBodyDocument(Blob.valueof('test'));
req.setTimeout(120000);

Http h = new Http();
HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
```

I am facing error as method undefined at line

```
req.setBodyDocument(Blob.valueof('test'));
```

Can anyone help me with this.

FYI: I also created the document and passed it as parameter still the error is same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the [DOCS](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_httprequest.htm) it is clear that the parameter the `setbodyDocument` required is a `Dom.Document`

> Type: Dom.Document

You are attempting to set it using a blob

Refer to [Document Class Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_xml_dom_document.htm#apex_classes_xml_dom_document) to understand how to create it.

You also cannot set both the `body` and `bodyDocument`

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
String endpoint = 'https://content.dropboxapi.com/1/files_put/auto/home/Private%20Salesforce%20Documents/Opportunities/test1.txt'; 

req.setEndpoint(endpoint); 
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + 'testAccessCode');
req.setMethod('PUT');
req.setBodyDocument(New Dom.Document());
req.setTimeout(120000);

Http h = new Http();
HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
```

works just fine. Without removing the `setBody` you get

> System.CalloutException: HTTP body already defined

Which is not the **same error** as you state in your comment

Comment: I also created the document and passed it as parameter still the error is same

Comment: @KrishnaBidwai - No you did not. Error is not same. Error is pretty specific -

Comment: small miss here.. setBody is comented. Also, Moreover I am not sure if this the working code to create file in dropbox as I have read and as per my understanding I have developed this

Comment: @KrishnaBidwai - The code I posted works just fine (makes the callout) in exec anon. It requires more than just commenting out `setBody` . you cannot use a blob in the parameter and your edits to your question still show you are doing that.

Comment: Thanks @Eric. Worked perfectly. Just want to go in deep what's the difference between in Dom.Document and just Document.

Comment: Do you know where to find the docs? It's explained there better than I could.